# How can I write a whitespace-only text node in XML output of XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslcompiledtransform

We have a messaging pipeline which include XML-to-XML transforms.

For a source document like this (which may also be in one line without formatting):

```
<doc>
  <a>Foo</a>
  <b>Bar1</b>
  <b>Bar2</b>
  <b>Bar3</b>
  <c>Baz</c>
</doc>
```

I need the XML output of the transform to be (note the line breaks):

```
<x>Bar1
Bar2
Bar3</x>
```

But the output I'm getting is:

```
<x>Bar1Bar2Bar3</x>
```

The stylesheet looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <x>
      <xsl:for-each select="//b">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
          <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>  <!-- something wrong here? -->
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </x>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I add a non-whitespace character to the text node then I end up with the new-line being preserved.  So, if I modify the `xsl:text` node to (note the added hyphen):

```
<xsl:text>-&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
```

then I get the output:

```
<x>Bar1-
Bar2-
Bar3</x>
```

How can I generate the desired output?

Note that we're limited to XSLT 1.0.

## Update

I've done some more testing.  Below is full code to reproduce the issue. Interestingly, this code reproduces the issue when run under .Net Framework 4.5 and .Net Core 2.1, but it gives the desired output when run under Mono.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace xslt
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(@"<doc><a>Foo</a><b>Bar1</b><b>Bar2</b><b>Bar3</b><c>Baz</c></doc>");

            var xsl = new XmlDocument();
            xsl.LoadXml(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration='yes' method='xml' version='1.0' />

    <xsl:template match='/'>
        <x>
        <xsl:for-each select='//b'>
            <xsl:value-of select='.' />
            <xsl:if test='position() != last()'>
                <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>  <!-- something wrong here? -->
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </x>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>");

            var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
            xslt.Load(xsl);
            
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                xslt.Transform(doc, null, stream);
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>` (using Unix linebreak instead of Windows' one)? It'll give you the desired output. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, and I get the same bad result.  It looks like a whitespace-only text node is being stripped during output.

Comment: Where do you "add [the] non-whitespace character"s?

Comment: @zx485 In the question I showed a hyphen (`'-'`) added in the `xsl:text` node just before the CrLf.

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced using your code: http://xsltransform.net/gVrtEo1 -- BTW, this has nothing to do with "preserving" whitespace.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  Hmm. I'm using the .Net XslCompiledTransform class to do the transform.  Maybe the issue is in the XmlWriter used to write the output file.

Comment: You can see it's working fine with MS XslCompiledTransform too: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqX I am afraid anything that happens after the transformation is out of my scope of experience.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  See question update.  Looks like xsltfiddle is probably using Mono to run the transform.  The problem repros with the code above under .Net 4.5 and .Net Core 2.1 on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I preserve whitespace-only text node in XML output of XSLT

If you really want to preserve the `text()` nodes between the `b` elements, you can match them with the XPath expression

```
text()[preceding::*[1][self::b]][following::*[1][self::b]]
```

and copy their whole content with an `xsl:copy-of`. The whole set of templates could look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/doc">
    <x>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </x>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="text()" />

<xsl:template match="text()[preceding::*[1][self::b]][following::*[1][self::b]]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

This copies also the whitespaces in between and not only the newlines, so the output looks like

```
<x>Bar1-
  Bar2
  Bar3</x>
```

Comment: Okay, but I also need the desired output to be produced if the source doucument is all on one line (ie. `<doc><a>Foo</a><b>…</b><c>Baz</c></doc>`.

Comment: And that technique also includes spaces/tabs between nodes, not just line breaks.

Comment: @AndrewCooper so it's not really about preserving the whitespace that's in the input, it's about ensuring that there is whitespace in the output regardless what is in the input? That's a significantly different requirement, so it would be a good idea to edit the question to say so.

Comment: @MichaelKay  My question never said anything about preserving whitespace in the input, and I added a clarification to say that the input formatting is not important.

Comment: @AndrewCooper Your title says *"preserve white-space only text nodes"*. In XSLT, that can mean only one thing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256144(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AndrewCooper shows how easy it is to confuse people when writing requirements. Those of us familiar with XSLT all assumed you were using "preserve" in the sense it is used in the spec.

Comment: @MichaelKay: I guess that I found a bug in Saxon 9.9.0.1J. Because I didn't find a link on your website to report a bug, I'll just post it here: Using the (invalid!) expression `<xsl:value-of select="string-join(count(x))" />` crashes Saxon completely with a java.lang.ClassCastException. Maybe that's interesting to you.

Comment: It would indeed be interesting but we'll need a full repro not just an isolated code fragment to reproduce it. Sorry you didn't find the link to our support site, it is saxonica.plan.io.

Comment: @MichaelKay: I filed the bug as `Bug #3986`, but I couldn't transmit if fully, because the code formatting is quite different from SO. Maybe you can make some sense of it.

Comment: Yes, wouldn't it be nice to have a standard markup language... Actually we've converted it to use Markdown which is supposedly what SO uses, but there are many different flavours.

Comment: @MichaelKay  I've removed the word "preserved" from the question title.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by adding a script block to the stylesheet to build the newline-separated value.

I'm still interested to know if it's possible with pure XSL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <x>
      <xsl:value-of select='userCSharp:JoinLines(//b)' />
    </x>
  </xsl:template>

  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="userCSharp">
    <![CDATA[

public string JoinLines(XPathNodeIterator nodes)
{
  var builder = new StringBuilder();
  while (nodes.MoveNext())
  {
    builder.AppendLine(nodes.Current.Value);
  }
  return builder.ToString().Trim();
}

    ]]>
  </msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It **is** possible with pure XSLT - as you have been shown. Your problem is not with XSLT, but with the implementing workflow. You should retag your question.